# Add custom block on success checkout page on Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, static-block, onepage-checkout

I am trying to add a product list on checkout success page.
I edited the file: `app\design\frontend\default\MY_THEME\layout\checkout.xml`

I changed

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
    <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb"><crumbName>home</crumbName><crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title></crumbInfo></action>
            <action method="addCrumb"><crumbName>checkout</crumbName><crumbInfo><label>Checkout</label><title>Checkout</title></crumbInfo></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="checkout.success">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>checkout/success.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list-limit.phtml">
            <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

to

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
    <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb"><crumbName>home</crumbName><crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title></crumbInfo></action>
            <action method="addCrumb"><crumbName>checkout</crumbName><crumbInfo><label>Checkout</label><title>Checkout</title></crumbInfo></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="checkout.success">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>checkout/success.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list-limit.phtml">
            <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

But this hid the `success.phtml` page and show the product list.

I tried several other ways but not loaded anything.

Somebody can help me?

Comment: What sort of product list are you trying to add?

Answer (score 1):

you can try below one

```
 <checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
    <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list-limit.phtml">
            <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

Hope this will work